# Repository for Dolphin Platform spring-boot-archetype

Tags: repository, dolphin-platform

Can you confirm the repository to use to use the Dolphin Platform 'spring-boot-archetype'?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Maven archetypes for the [Dolphin Platform](http://www.dolphin-platform.io) are available by Maven Central. You can find the Spring Boot archetype [here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22spring-boot-archetype%22).

Yesterday [we released the version 0.7](http://www.guigarage.com/2015/12/dolphin-platform-0-7-has-been-released/) of Dolphin Platform that adds a KumuluzEE based archetype, too. Currently this one is still not visible at Maven Central but might appear the next hours.
If you want to create a project based on the archetype in an IDE like IntelliJ you can find a description [here](http://www.guigarage.com/2015/12/dolphin-platform-jumpstart/).

If you want to create a project from the shell you only need this command:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.canoo.dolphin-platform -DarchetypeArtifactId=spring-boot-archetypetype
```

Comment: A much shorter command: mvn archetype:generate -Dfilter=com.canoo.dolphin-platform: